# there's a way to create class objects dynamically?

Tags: c#

I have a queue containing a bunch of class objects.
If possible, I'd like to get them all and instantiate them as new objects dynamically.

Of course, such a description is not possible, but as an image, it is possible to collectively execute it like this.

```
// queueModel:the queue that's holding original class objects.
// also classModel has property "OriginalClassName" and it's including class name as string
// also corresponding classes are ready for new objects.

string className;
object obj = null;

do
{
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(queueModel.Peek());
    className = jObject["OriginalClassName"].ToString();
    **className** obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<**className**>(queueModel.Dequeue());
    //If you specify it manually, it will look like this
    // SomeClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(queueModel.Dequeue());

} while (queueModel.Count != 0);
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Say if you could write `dynamic obj = JsonConvert...`, What would you do with it? How would you know what methods/properties to use if the type could be anything?

Comment: That would kind of defeat the entire point of the type system....

Comment: I already have classes for them.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

Comment: Seeing as how you're using Newtonsoft.Json, I'd recommend you create a common base class for your models and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/9363973) Q&A to solve your problem. Alternatively, you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/9363973) Q&A to use reflection to call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` with the appropriate type parameter.

Comment: probably transfering class objects are just bad idea. (It's not must in my case)
I just wanted to create them as class for exercise and afterward this things happend.
Anyway i will look into reflection thing.
Thanks.